# Pathos Parallel processing in python Error

Tags: python, parallel-processing, parallel-python

Keep getting this error when attempting parallel process in python:

```
    An error has occured during the function import
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/runner/.site-packages/ppft/__main__.py", line 100, in 
run
    six.exec_(__fobj)
  File "<string>", line 46, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ppft.exceptions'
A fatal error has occured during the function execution
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/.site-packages/ppft/__main__.py", line 109, 
in run
    __f = locals()[ppc.str_(__fname)]
KeyError: 'run_test'
```

Here is the jist of my code:

```
from pathos.pools import ParallelPool as Pool
urls = ["https://www.baidu.com", "https://google.com/"]

def run_test(url):
    #getting and storing a bunch of JSON data from urls in here
    #content here did not produce errors when doing single process

pool =  Pool(4)
print(pool.map(run_test, urls))
pool.close() 
pool.join()
```

Please can someone help me understand the error/issue?

Comment: On which OS are you running your code (Windows vs Linux/Mac *does* make a difference when using multiprocessing)? Also: do you, by any chance, have a module/package named `ppft`? It's a common mistake to use the same name of a library and end up getting errors because the code imports the wrong file...

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta I'm using Python 3.6.1 on Linux. I think so- when I enter help("modules"), ppft is listed. Not quite sure what you mean in the last sentence.. when would i have used the same library? do I need to delete ppft somehow? (Sorry if these are dumb questions. Pretty new to this & really appreciate your help!)

Comment: I can not reproduce this error with an empty body of  `run_test` on Mac.